# Динамическая работа Custom Fields ACF, как осуществить?

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin

На WordPress есть замечательный плагин [Custom Fields ACF](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), где можно создать произвольные поля в специальных настройках и потом пользоваться в определенной таксономии. А есть ли возможность генерировать произвольные плагины при написании post'a. Другими словами можно ли заменить стандартный Custom Fields на Custom Fields ACF [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не пойму о чем речь, вот пример вывода полей ACF в админке: http://take.ms/KznhUF

Comment: @KAGGDesign, мне хотелось бы создавать поля прямо в посте, а не переходить в настройки и добавлять их там. Т.е часть настроек перенести в раздел добавление/редактирования поста/ Чтобы там, где на картинке надпись "Добавить поле", можно было добавлять поля с ACF

Comment: Нет, такого функционала я никогда не видел. Вряд ли он существует.